# In what format does this variable need to be?

Tags: python

This is one of the programs I need to make on finals. The assignment is to write a name of racer and his three throws after that. For example: Adam 150 60 70. Then i need to find his max and min throw. I also need to write this data in txt file. I stripped this var of all text, only numbers remained. But I have problem with basic math functions. It takes e.g. number 150 as separate digits 1 5 0. I assume I have this variable in wrong format. I tried to convert it to almost everything, but nothing worked. I know this is silly problem, but if you know how to fix or rewrite this program I would appreciate it.

```
from fileinput import close
from string import ascii_letters

alp = ascii_letters
n = int(input('Number of racers: '))
subor = open('hod_ostepom_tx.txt','r+')
with open('hod_ostepom_tx.txt','r+') as f:
    f.truncate(0)

for i in range (n):
    name = input('Name of racer and his three throws: ')
    subor.write(name + '\n')
    for ele in alp:
        name = name.replace(ele,'')
        name = name.replace(' ','')
    print('Maximum is: ',max(name))
    print('Minimum is: ',min(name))

subor = close()
```

> Name of racer and his three throws: Adam 150 60 70

> Maximum is:  7
> Minimum is:  0

In this case I would expect outcome of Maximum is : 150 Minimum is : 60

Comment: Have you heard of the string `split` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useful function `str.split()` to split the string by spaces, thus by doing this:

```
user_input = input('Name of racer and his three throws: ').split()
```

`user_input` will be `['Adam', '150', '60', '70']`. You'll only need to get the name and convert string numbers to integer numbers. To remove first element form a list you can use `.pop()` function:

```
name = user_input.pop(0)
```

Now there's no `'Adam'` in the list, only throws. To convert the ist of string to a list of numbers, you can use functional style:

```
throws = list(map(int, user_input))
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know that .split function does that. I guess i need to study more.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a string. After you apply your replacements, `name` is still a string which contains only numbers. For your example `name = "1506070"`. When you call `max` and `min` on a string it returns the character with the highest and lowest character code, 7 and 0 respectively. You can achieve what you want using the `split` function on the string. `name_list = name.split(" ")` will give a list `name_list = ["Adam", "150", "60", "70"]`. You can then use a list comprehension to convert the strings to integers:

```
name_list = name_list[1:] # Includes items at index 1 and after to get rid of name
name_list = [int(x) for x in name_list]
```

Then you can do `max(name_list)` or `min(name_list)` as the elements are integers and should give you what you want.

Comment: Setting `item = int(item)` won't change the list, only the local copy of the item

Comment: I didn't think that one through, I've replaced it with a list comprehension now. Thanks for pointing it out.